# What does the difficulty level affect in Age of Wonders: Planetfall?

Tags: age-of-wonders-planetfall

I'm starting the main campaign and I see a difficulty dropdown menu with "Beginner", "Advanced", and "Expert". I don't see any tooltips or other information that let me know how that actually changes the difficulty of the game though.

Comment: If it is anything like other 4X games, it's most likely just giving either the player or the AI bonuses on all forms of income, like production, currency, research etc. I'm not sure though, I don't own the game and such things usually tend to be hidden somewhere inside config files.